# How can I resolve this SSL report score?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

Report:

> The server is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. If possible, disable SSL 3 to mitigate.
>
> The server supports only older protocols, but not the current best TLS 1.2.
>
> The server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocol versions.

1. Is it good to disable SSL 3?
2. Is it good to enable TLS 1.2?
3. Is there a solution to improve the SSL Score?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is it good to disable SSL 3?

Generally yes.

> 2. Is it good to enable TLS 1.2?

Generally yes.

> 3. Is there a solution to improve the SSL Score?

In broad strokes:

- Regardless of what web server you are running:

  - Update your server software.
  - Disable SSL3.
  - Enable TLS1.2.
- If running the Microsoft *IIS* web server:

  - Download and run [*IISCrypto*](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto).
  - Press *"Best Practices"* button.
  - Press *"Apply"* button.
  - Close IISCrypto.
  - Reboot server.
- If running another web server:

  - Implement crypto config from [*Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator*](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much StackzOfZtuff.

I will try this very soon will come back with results.